# What's the reason for error message? I am using VS 2010 professional edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What's the reason for error message "The snapshot is out of date and cannot be used anymore because type tree has been updated, A new snapshow needs to be acquired"?

This error appeared right after I launched VS2010 and added username/pwd to connect to TFS repository.

I am using VS 2010 professional edition.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/9331c951-01ce-47d5-8d70-68a20b1c7a60), you need to make sure that you have "Windows Phone" selected as the debug configuration, not x86.

Comment: I am not using vs2010 for windows phone development. Why am I down-voted?

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with whether or not you're using Windows Phone for development. Try adding more details to your question. I've never heard of this error message in any other context.

Comment: I'm making a game using XNA (Xbox 360, not Windows Phone) and Visual C# 2010 Express.

I've been building & deploying regularly, but now I've gotten the error
    "Error 1 The snapshot is out of date and can not be used anymore because the binder has been updated. A new snapshot needs to be acquired.  Line 0 Column 0"

Can't find any other useful info about this online (found a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742959/the-snapshot-is-out-of-date), but no resolutions or workarounds) & it won't let me deploy or run.

What do "snapshot" & "binder" refer to?

Comment: Just google it: http://alexgamedev.blogspot.com/2012/02/xna-snapshot-is-out-of-date-and-can-not.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It happened to me with VS2012 as well after loading the project without source control binding, a local simple WinForms project. All I needed to do was Clean & Rebuild. After that the problem was solved.

Comment: I found that sometimes you also have to completely exit and reload Visual Studio 2012 after doing a clean & rebuild for it to actually go away.

Comment: @RobertOschler Thanks for the info. I have used VS2012 little recently and haven't found the problem anymore.

Comment: For my case it was not necessary to restart the IDE: File -> Close Solution; then, Recent Projects and Solutions -> Click on the appropriate solution or project.

Comment: I had to close the tab which had the error. Restarting VS2012 didn't seem to make a difference after the clean.

Comment: I just deleted the obj folder and reopened the project.

Answer (score 17):

This is a bug in Visual Studio. According to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742959/the-snapshot-is-out-of-date "We've taken a closer look at this problem and it isn't one that we'll be able to solve in the next release of Visual Studio."

They recommend waiting around until the background language parser service is done (or, in other words, don't try to be *too* productive there partner.) My experience is that closing all documents, cleaning the solution, rebuilding it and then closing and re-opening with a pause after does remove the error.

Until you do something silly, like edit code. Then all bets are off again as to when it  reoccurs.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I put the actual salient points in the answer: links die. The key point is that Microsoft knows about it and has kicked the can down until the full rewrite of the parser is done.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger. If the links dead, I've given you an opportunity to do something about it and/or avoided anyone else wasting their time clicking on it. If you want to ignore it, then do it. Don't remind me that links die.

Comment: I'm very sorry if that came across with the incorrect tone. Perhaps some of my anger at *links only* posts came through unintentionally. I really hate posts with a URL and no actual answer.

Comment: Yes, closing all the documents, then doing a clean & rebuild all got rid of the problem!

Comment: Updated link: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742959/the-snapshot-is-out-of-date

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue with VS2012 and after rebuilding the solution twice, I still saw the same error message.
Following an advice from a post from [this site](http://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742959/the-snapshot-is-out-of-date), I closed the Designer tab, reopened it from the Solution Explorer, and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Closing all my open documents cleared the error for me

Answer (score 5):

I got this error too, but after I `unload project` and `reload project`, the problem was resolved.

Comment: I had this problem and this comment provided the solution. Weird error I have never seen before

Answer (score 3):

Simply restarting Visual Studio 2012 was a workaround for me, but it kept happening about every hour and having to restart visual studio that often was very annoying.

I also found [this post](http://alexgamedev.blogspot.ca/2012/02/xna-snapshot-is-out-of-date-and-can-not.html) which suggests that the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) are the problem and to simply turn off the **Automatic Brace Completion** in *Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools*. Since making this change I haven't seen the error message again :)

I'll note though that I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the OP is using Visual Studio 2010, but the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) are available for VS 2010 too, so this may still fix the problem in VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue persists in VS2013, but no amount of Clean/Rebuild or restarting VS will help. The only way I can do a successful publish, is to disable the **AutoT4MVC** extension.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too.  I closed Visual Studio 2012 and opened it again and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had conflicting class names / namespaces. I was referencing a UserControl from a different DLL in my XAML file which had the same name as my XAML file (class name). Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used Visual Studio 2012, and just faced this error on my Windows 8. It seems like Turning off the VM and restarting Visual Studio fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this with VS2010.

I had a form with a user control (UCa) with a user control (UCa) from a different project on it. Made a change to the UCb then flicked to the designer for the form and boom! Snapshot error.

Resolved by a full clean and then rebuilding just the UCb project before building the rest of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and I got this error when starting Visual Studio, letting TFS connect to the server, and THEN opening my solution. The fix was simply closing VS and launching the solution directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my two cents in here as well.

I've tried every combination of Clean, Rebuild, Restart, etc. What I've found is that restarting Visual Studio usually makes the problem go away for at least one Publish. Here's the weird part, though. You can also fix the problem by doing absolutely nothing. If you just let Visual Studio sit for about a minute or two, and *then* publish, it will usually work just fine. There's some background voodoo going on here, and waiting for it to finish seems to do the trick.

I have a solution with two parts that need published. One is a WCF service application, and the other is the ASP.NET MVC5 website itself. Anytime I publish the services, and then try to publish the site I'll see this error. I can publish the services, restart VS, and then publish the site, **OR** I can publish the services, go get a drink, and then publish the site. As long as I give VS a chance to "settle" between any kind of rebuild and the publishing of the site, everything seems to work as expected.

Take a walk, come back, problem solved. OR if you don't have the time. Clean, Rebuild, Restart, Publish (lather, rinse, repeat).